# Disable translations update on module enable

Tags: 8

I have large site with 15 languages, when working locally If I enable some module over UI (or reinstall it) auto update of translations kicks off and this last for some time. I really don't need that while developing things, how could I disable this feature?

Answer (score 1):

you can configure the translation.import_enabled key in locale.settings config
a way to do that is with drush :

```
drush cset locale.settings translation.import_enabled 0
```

hope this helps

Comment: Did that, didn't help. I installed some module for testing and again "Updating configuration translations" started and I need to wait for that to finish.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to disable update by:

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_module_implements_alter().
 */
function MY_MODULE_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'modules_installed') {
    $moduleHandler = \Drupal::service('module_handler');
    if ($moduleHandler->moduleExists('locale')) {
      unset($implementations['locale']);
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Implements hook_modules_installed().
 */
function MY_MODULE_modules_installed() {
  $moduleHandler = \Drupal::service('module_handler');
  if ($moduleHandler->moduleExists('locale')) {
    locale_system_set_config_langcodes();
  }
}
```